# Chicago Manual of Style footnote question: one author, split source

Tags: citations

I'm citing a journal article that was published in two parts, one week apart. Everything is the same--the title, author, journal, etc.

Cornelia G. Harcum, “A Study of Dietetics among the Romans,” Classical Weekly, Dec. 9, 1918, Vol. 12, No. 8 (Dec. 9, 1918): 58-61.

Cornelia G. Harcum, “A Study of Dietetics among the Romans,” Classical Weekly, Dec. 16, 1918, Vol. 12, No. 9 (Dec. 16, 1918): 66-68.

How do I do the shortened footnote for either the first or the second half of the article? These are two distinct publications, but the shortened footnote would have all the same information: Harcum, Dietetics, page number.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to shorten the text? These are two separate publications, it makes sense to have both referenced in full.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked as a copy editor for a journal that uses Chicago Style. My discipline has Chicago Style as a preference as well.

I believe I have found the answer to your question, however, it's unrelated to Chicago Style. I went to JSTOR to look at your articles. Reviewing the primary sources, the title of the articles is different from what you've written. The title referred to by JSTOR for the second article is "A Study of Dietetics among the Romans (Concluded)." Just go with that title for the shortened form, as it's different from the first.

Here's a permalink:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/4387739

[image]

Comment: I really like answers where the person answering has done some research. I'd give it more than +1 if I could.

Answer (score 0):

The shortened footnote does not necessarily need to have exactly the same words as the actual title. When you first present the first article in full, you can add in parenthesis "henceforth referred to as "shortened title (Part I)" and for the second article "shortened title" (Part II). In fact, you could just have a simple number, such as "shortened title 1" and "shortened title 2". The letters A and B are also fine.

Comment: I don't think this is correct because the suggestions you've given will make it seem like those are the correct titles. There would need to be an editor's note to state so.